# MySQL - Select query with first rows where a field value > 10 without ordering by this field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like to make a  `SELECT` in my player table where, in the result, the first rows are the players who played more than 10 games. What is preventing me from just doing an `ORDER BY total_games` is that I would like to `ORDER` by `signin_year` and then by `player_type` for the following result.

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| username     | signin_year | player_type  | total_games  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| John Doe     | 2019        | 10           | 62           |
| Jon Skeet    | 2019        | 20           | 2479         |
| Shmebulock   | 2020        | 10           | 82           |
| Norman       | 2020        | 20           | 154          |
| Bob          | 2019        | 10           | 3            |
| Alice        | 2020        | 10           | 9            |
| Community    | 2020        | 20           | -1           |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I tried a bunch of `WHERE`s and `ORDER BY`s but I can't seems to make it work, is this even possible or will I need to use a subquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ORDER BY` along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM player
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN total_games > 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    signin_year,
    player_type;
```

This places players having played more than 10 total games first, followed by all other players.  Within these two blocks, the data is sorted ascending by signin year followed by ascending player type.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you